# How can I pass parameters (an object and a string) between threads c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parameters, parameter-passing

I've got this little piece of code. How can I pass the parameters (the object and the string) to the thread (in the line "`th = new Thread(play);`")?

Thanks!

```
private Thread th = null;

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    [...]
    th = new Thread(play);
    th.Start();
}

private void play(object sender, string name)
{
    [...]
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h2f2459(v=vs.110).aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to change the signature for your `play()` method:

```
private void play(object data)
{
    object[] array = (object[])data;  // data is actually an array of objects

    object sender = array[0];
    string name = (string)array[1];
}
```

Then you just have to change the way you start the thread:

```
th.Start(new object[] { sender, "whatever name" });
```